# Java For Loop - What is i++ doing in For Loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, operator-precedence

So program problem, the program will print 4. My question is what does i++ do in the for loop? The i++ is throwing me off a bit because I'm thinking when the for loop runs, i=1 intially, the for loop runs, now i = 2, but because there is an i++ inside the for loop after total+= i, my thinking is that it goes from i = 1 to i = 3.

```
public class LoopExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)

        {

        total += i;

        i++;

        }

        System.out.println(total);

     }

}
```

Comment: Well... why did you put it there? What value of total did you expect? What is your problem?

Comment: Your thinking is alright.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is right: you are incrementing `i` **IN** the for loop on top of the increment statement.

Just remove the `i++` statement within the for loop if you want `i` to go from `1` to `5` with  step of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your hypothesis is right the `i++` inside the loop increment the `i`.
It's equivalent to

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i = i + 2) {
    total += i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increments are happening twice here, yes you are correct here: i will be 1 then it will be 3 then it will be 5.

Because i is incremented twice, once inside the loop and then in for statement.

for loop has 3 operations: Initialization, condition check, increment/decrement

Initialization happens only once.
Condition is checked until it return false.
Increment/decrement operation is your i++

`for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)//int i=1 is initialization, which happens once. i<5 is condition, i++ is increment.`

> Here is how your loop works:
>
> i=1
>
> `i<5` is true so it goes inside the loop
>
> change the value of total to 1. 0 = 0+1 
>   `total+=total+i`
>
> increment the value of i by 1. Now i = 2.
>
> now the control goes to the third operation of for loop that is
>   **;i++**. Again the value of i is incremented by 1. i=3

If you want increments in 1, delete the i++ statement inside the for loop

OR in the loop itself like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 5; )
```